# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

---

Hello i am beginner in android developping app when i try to save image from my host i get this error

this app its for changing phone background and whatsapp background when i want to change whatsapp background i get this error

---

```
   04-07 20:00:04.655 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd W/dalvikvm: threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b65648)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:530)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:603)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd.SlideImageActivity$SaveTask.doInBackground(SlideImageActivity.java:599)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd.SlideImageActivity$SaveTask.doInBackground(SlideImageActivity.java:558)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
04-07 20:00:04.659 19211-19269/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
04-07 20:00:06.475 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager: Activity com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd.SlideImageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52c576f8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd.SlideImageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52c576f8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd.SlideImageActivity$SaveTask.onPreExecute(SlideImageActivity.java:582)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd.SlideImageActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SlideImageActivity.java:272)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:74)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:44)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:77)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:163)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:738)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:187)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-07 20:00:07.247 19211-19211/com.anasraf.whatsappwallpaperhd E/WindowManager:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import lib.cropper.wallpaper.CropImageView;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class SetAsWallpaperActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private CropImageView mCropImageView;
    String[] mImages,mCatName;
    int position;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_set_as_wallpaper);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        Intent i=getIntent();
        mImages=i.getStringArrayExtra("WALLPAPER_IMAGE_URL");
        mCatName=i.getStringArrayExtra("WALLPAPER_IMAGE_CATEGORY");
        position=i.getIntExtra("POSITION_ID", 0);
        mCropImageView = (CropImageView)findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);

          ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext()));
          ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_DETAILS+mImages[position], new ImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(arg2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }

     public void setAsWallpaper(View view) throws IOException
        {
         (new SetWallpaperTask(SetAsWallpaperActivity.this)).execute("");
        }

     public class SetWallpaperTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>
     {
         private Context context;
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
         Bitmap bmImg = null;

         public SetWallpaperTask(Context context) {
             this.context = context;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.onPreExecute();

             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
             pDialog.setMessage("Wallpaer set ...");
             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
             pDialog.show();

         }

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
             /* TODO Auto-generated method stub */
            bmImg=mCropImageView.getCroppedImage();
             return null;   
         }


         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); // --The method context() is undefined for the type SetWallpaperTask
             try {
                wpm.setBitmap(bmImg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             pDialog.dismiss();
             Toast.makeText(SetAsWallpaperActivity.this, "WallPaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
             interstitial = new InterstitialAd(SetAsWallpaperActivity.this);
             // Insert the Ad Unit ID
             interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
             AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
             // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
             interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
             // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
             interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                 public void onAdLoaded() {
                     // Call displayInterstitial() function
                     // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
                     if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                         interstitial.show();
                     }

                 }
             });
             finish();
         }
     }

     @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
        {       
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
            {
            case android.R.id.home: 
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

---

this image loader

public class ImageLoader {

```
    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id= R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
           queuePhoto(url, imageView);
           imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=150;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
            {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }//else
               // photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your stack trace says `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Does that help? How big is your image?...

Comment: the size of some image are  between 1 to 2 Mo

Comment: Its rarely the immediate image-  its the total memory of your app.  Either you're using way too much or your have a leak.  Use a heap profiler to figure out where your memory is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is too big. Either reduce the resolution or compress it. If it is a jpg then convert it into png. This [website](http://tinypng.com/) compresses png by 50-70% without any discernable loss of quality.